# ¿Como mostrar los datos seleccionados dentro un Datagridview en Windows Form c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagrid

Tengo este Datagridview

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de darle click en enviar quiero que me aparesca en un messagebox los elemento que seleccione con el checkbox y me muestre(codigo), (nombre completo)

Estoy intentando con este metodo

```
 string text = string.Empty;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewSMS.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["Estado"].Value))
                    {
                        text += $@"{row.Cells["Codigo"].Value} - {row.Cells["NombreCompleto"].Value} 
                {Environment.NewLine}";
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show(text);
```

me lanza este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado?

Comment: @M.Gress con foreach y ya lo puese

Comment: ¿Y que resultado has tenido con el código que muestras?

Comment: @M.Gress un error de DBNull

Comment: o sea, row.Cells["Estado"].Value te esta devolviendo null... tenes que verificar el valor antes de hacer el convert

Comment: con una conversión vasto  `if (Convert.IsDBNull(row.Cells["Estado"].Value) ? false : (bool)row.Cells["Estado"].Value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e ahi mi solucion, espero que les sirva.

```
 string text = string.Empty;
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewSMS.Rows)
                {
                    if (Convert.IsDBNull(row.Cells["Estado"].Value) ? false : (bool)row.Cells["Estado"].Value)
                    {
                    text += $@"{row.Cells["codigo"].Value} - {row.Cells["NombreCompleto"].Value} {Environment.NewLine}";
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show(text);
```